# Hypergeometric identities

Tags: hypergeometric-functions, co.combinatorics, nt.number-theory, special-functions

Let $m,k$ be positive integers with $k\le m$. Does anyone know some hypergeometric identities that imply 
$$\sum_{j=0}^k\frac{(-1/2)_{k-j}(m+1)_j(-m)_j}{(1/2)_j(k-j)!j!}
=\frac{(-m-\frac{1}{2})_k(m+\frac{1}{2})_k}{(\frac{1}{2})_kk!}$$ 
where $a_k=a(a+1)\cdots (a+k-1)$ is the Pochhammer's symbol.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Treating both sides as coefficients of $x^k$ in a power series with variable $x$, the left-hand side turns into a power-series product, one factor representing $\sqrt{1-x}$. We end up with a special case of the known hypergeometric identity
$$(1-x)^{a+b-c} {}_2F_1(a,b;c;x) = {}_2F_1(c-a,c-b;c;x)$$
with $a = m+1$, $b = -m$, $c = 1/2$.
Cf. (34) of [this MathWorld entry](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunction.html).

Answer (score 6):

Equivalently to ccorn's answer, the sum may be written as 
$$\frac {(-1/2)_{k}}{k!}{}_{3}F_{2}\left({{m+1,-m,-k}\atop {3/2-k,1/2}}
\Bigm |1\right)$$ which may be evaluated by [Saalschütz's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function#Saalsch.C3.BCtz.27s_theorem) (also called the Pfaff-Saalschütz theorem).